# Cannot instantiate the type CleverSearchTimer?

Tags: java

Below is a test class for the CleverSearchTimer and the Interface CleverSearchTimer

```
public class CleverSearchTimerTest {

private static SimpleRandomCount srctest;
private static CleverSearchTimer ssttest;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() {
    srctest = new SimpleRandomCount(25);
    ssttest = new CleverSearchTimer();
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
}

public void findKthElementTestRegular() throws IndexingError{
    assertEquals(ssttest.findKthElement(srctest.array(),4),21);
}

public void FindKthElementTestBoundaryLow() throws IndexingError{
    assertEquals(ssttest.findKthElement(srctest.array(),25), 0);
}

public void FindKthElementTestBoundaryHigh() throws IndexingError{
    assertEquals(ssttest.findKthElement(srctest.array(),1), 24);
}

public void FindKthElementTestErroneous() throws IndexingError{
    equals(ssttest.findKthElement(srctest.array(), 30));
}

@Test
public void test() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");
}

}
```

CleverSearchTimer:

```
public interface CleverSearchTimer {
/**
* Find the kth largest element in an array of ints
* @param array — array of ints
* @param k — index of the element to be found
* @return — kth largest int in array
* @throws IndexingError — if k is not a valid index
*/
   public int findKthElement(int[] array, int k)
   throws IndexingError;



/** Find the time it takes to find the kth element
* @param array — array of ints
* @param k — the index of the element to be found
* @return — the time taken to find the kth largest element
* @throws IndexingError — if k is not a valid index
*/

   public double time(int[] array,int k)
   throws IndexingError;
} // end of interface TimedSearch
```

An error appears on the line "ssttest = new CleverSearchTimer();" "Cannot instantiate type CleverSearchTimer".

I think this is because you can't instantiate an interface in a test class. Is there another way to do that?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces cannot be instantiated. You have to make a class that implements that interface, then instantiate that class. Anonymous classes are an exception, but do not apply in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create a class that implements the interface

```
public MyClass implements MyInterface {...}
```

Be aware you will need to **implement** all the methods you specified in your interface